# Vue-js - Update input value based on Object instances in array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-model

I want to update an `input`'s value with the times a specific object appears in the object list. Is there any way to bind that data using `v-model`?

**app.js**

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#ticket',
data: {
    menuProducts: [
       'Beer',
       'Peanuts'
    ],
    ticketProducts: [
        {
            name: 'Beer',
            cat: 'Drink',
            specs: 'Lager'
        },{
            name: 'Peanuts',
            cat: 'Snack'
        },
        {
            name: 'Beer',
            cat: 'Drink',
            specs: 'Light'
        },
    ]
}
...
```

**view.html**

```
<div class="card-frame col-lg-6 col-xl-4" 
v-for="product in menuProducts">
    <div class="card product p-3 mb-4">
        <div class="info mt-3">
            <h5>@{{ product.nombre }}</h5>
            <input readonly type="number" value="0">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this example, I render a product card for each product in the menu. In each card, I want to update the `input` to know how many products are in my ticket (2 beers and 1 'peanuts').